# how to open links in _blank/ another page and override it to open different links in that particular window in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```
const newChildWindow = window.open(
    url, "_blank", `width="${altScreen.availWidth}", height="${altScreen.availHeight}"`
);

newChildWindow?.resizeTo(altScreen.availWidth, altScreen.availHeight);
newChildWindow?.moveTo(altScreen.left, 0);
```

```
fun1() {
    this.doSetup("http://www.google.com");  
}

fun2() {
    this.doSetup("http://www.twitter.com");
}

fun3() {
    this.doSetup("http://www.linkedin.com");
}
```

these functions are of 3 different buttons.
i am giving the url as arg, it is working fine, but because of "_blank" every link is opening in a different window, i want the "_blank" but links should override that particular window only.

is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can use like below way:
First Time use your code:

```
const newChildWindow = window.open(
              url, "_blank", `width="${altScreen.availWidth}", height="${altScreen.availHeight}"`
            );
            newChildWindow?.resizeTo(altScreen.availWidth, altScreen.availHeight);
            newChildWindow?.moveTo(altScreen.left, 0);
```

use this variable second time with below logic

```
newChildWindow.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

Comment: Thank you sir, that's exactly what i was searching for. But can you give an idea of how to make a logic of doing this at one click, eg: if i click any of 3 link for first time, it will open on _blank  and then if i again click same link or other links, it will replace that.

Comment: for that logic you just need to make one variable global say newChildWinow with null value & for first time you need to give Window.open() statement. on second time click you need to check that newChildWindow is not null then need to replace url

Comment: That logic seems right but i already tried that, if i give null to newChildWindow, then if condition will have to work for window.open then it turns to an object then else condition will never happen. if you give 2 if cond. then both will execute, because after 1st if it turns to object.